# SQL View. Select count... Where

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I am most confused with this one, so i d better ask the experts!

These are the rows returned by a custom query of mine.

```
Col1   Col2   Result
Font   Bold   a
Font   Bold   b
Font   Bold   a
Font   Italic a
```

Is there any way of using selecting count in the above (table) results in order getting this one?

```
Col1  Col2   ResultA  ResultB
Font  Bold   2        1
Font  Italic 1        0
```

****Update:****The values that should be counted as results are a and b.

p.s. Unfortunately i cannot post the full schema of the table.

Comment: can you add table structure please? and do you only have 2 result values?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a correlation between Result2's values and the rest of the data set. What is Result2 represent? It's not a SUM ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Result=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Result1, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Result=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Result2 
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1, col2, COUNT( result ) as result1  FROM table GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Please explain what it should count to get 1 in first and 0 in second row of your example.